# Android annotations with Android studio 2.0 beta

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-annotations

Trying to build my project with the new Android studio 2.0 beta, which uses gradle 2.1 and the new gradle 2.0.0 beta plugin.

I can see that the annotated classed are generated fine, but the I am getting a "Cannot find symbol" error from the compiler and the project does not compile.

It seems that the new gradle plugin maybe cannot see the generated classes or something similar.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

So after almost giving up on the new Gradle plugin, I found the answer!

It seems the problem is that to use the new Instant Run feature introduced in Android Studio 2.0, what they are doing is replacing the Application class with a new instrumented class, and AA 3 is having some problems with that.

The solution is to use the new (pre-released) AA 4, and change some small configurations.

It is explained in details in this wiki:
https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1639#issuecomment-165477743